# Admob customize

Tags: android, admob

I am new in using admob in a game. It is showing in the left upper corner but i want to show it in center. Here is my code. Thank you advance.

```
    Window window = getWindow();
    RelativeLayout adsLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams Param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Param.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14******");
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    adsLayout.addView(adView,Param);
    window.addContentView(adsLayout,Param);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should give a size to your adsLayout like fill_parent